# Getting user defined data from an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt

I am trying to build a program in Java that has 30 codes built in and if a user defines what number code he wants from 1 to 30, then a specific code will be displayed to him. So far I am stuck to the point where I have to get the data (6 digit numbers) out of my array. Maybe some of you can give me some advice on that?

Code:

```
package koodibaas;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class koodibaas extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TextField tfCount;
    private Label lblCount;
    private Button btnCount;

    public koodibaas() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lblCount = new Label("ENTER CODE?");
        add(lblCount);

        tfCount = new TextField("0", 10);
        add(tfCount);

        btnCount = new Button("GIVE ANSWER");
        add(btnCount);
        btnCount.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("koodibaas");
        setSize(400, 150);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void second(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[30];
        array[0] = 111111;
        array[1] = 888888;
        array[2] = 333333;
        array[3] = 555555;
        array[4] = 111111;
        array[5] = 643208;
        array[6] = 643208;
        array[7] = 643208;
        array[8] = 643208;
        array[9] = 643208;
        array[10] = 643208;
        array[11] = 643208;
        array[12] = 643208;
        array[13] = 643208;
        array[14] = 643208;
        array[15] = 643208;
        array[16] = 643208;
        array[17] = 643208;
        array[18] = 643208;
        array[19] = 643208;
        array[20] = 643208;
        array[21] = 643208;
        array[22] = 643208;
        array[23] = 643208;
        array[24] = 643208;
        array[25] = 643208;
        array[26] = 643208;
        array[27] = 643208;
        array[28] = 643208;
        array[29] = 643208;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        koodibaas app = new koodibaas(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        tfCount.setText(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Too broad. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your array outside

```
int[] array;
```

and initialize it by calling second method .

and access array from button onclick event

```
int number=Integer.parseInt(tfCount.getText());
tfCount.setText(String.valueOf(array[number]));
```

second method don't need to be a static method and there is no need of parameter

finally code should be

```
public class koodibaas extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int[] array;

    private TextField tfCount;

    private Label lblCount;

    private Button btnCount;

    public koodibaas() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lblCount = new Label("ENTER CODE?");

        add(lblCount);
        tfCount = new TextField("0", 10);
        add(tfCount);

        btnCount = new Button("GIVE ANSWER");
        add(btnCount);

        btnCount.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("koodibaas");
        setSize(400, 150);
        setVisible(true);
        second(); // call second to initialize array 

    }

    public void second() {
        array = new int[30];
        array[0] = 111111;
        array[1] = 888888;
        array[2] = 333333;
        array[3] = 555555;
        array[4] = 111111;
        array[5] = 643208;
        array[6] = 643208;
        array[7] = 643208;
        array[8] = 643208;
        array[9] = 643208;
        array[10] = 643208;
        array[11] = 643208;
        array[12] = 643208;
        array[13] = 643208;
        array[14] = 643208;
        array[15] = 643208;
        array[16] = 643208;
        array[17] = 643208;
        array[18] = 643208;
        array[19] = 643208;
        array[20] = 643208;
        array[21] = 643208;
        array[22] = 643208;
        array[23] = 643208;
        array[24] = 643208;
        array[25] = 643208;
        array[26] = 643208;
        array[27] = 643208;
        array[28] = 643208;
        array[29] = 643208;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        koodibaas app = new koodibaas();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        int number = Integer.parseInt(tfCount.getText());
        tfCount.setText(String.valueOf(array[number]));
    }

}
```